# Redirect Old Domain To New Domain But Exclude Add-On Domains? (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've spent all morning searching for an answer for this and can't get it to work...

I have a few add-on domains on my server and would like to redirect my primary domain to a new domain, but exclude those add-on domains.

Here's what I have in my htaccess file so far...

```
#Redirect from old domain to new domain with full path and query string, excluding add-on domains:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/SixFigureShortcut.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/JamesFrancisRecommends.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/zeroto10kcoaching.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://www.digitalprosperity.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The SixFigureShortcut.com and JamesFrancisRecommends.com folders in my FTP are capitalized like that, whereas the zeroto10kcoaching.com folder is all lower case.

It's doing the correct thing with the zeroto10kcoaching.com domain but not the SixFigureShortcut.com and JamesFrancisRecommends.com domains.

Any help?

Thanks!

James.

Comment: Which are your addon domains and which is your primary domain (that you want to redirect)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start talking about "addon" domains but then change to discuss the folders that these addon domains (presumably) map to? I would assume that the subdirectory is not part of the URL and therefore irrelevant here?

Presumably, the user is requesting something like `addon-domain.com/whatever` and it is this that you need to exclude from the redirect. In which case try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !addon-domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !addon-domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !addon-domain3\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://www.target-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing, as the earlier (erroneous) redirects will have been cached hard by the browser.